# IS the beej mantra mentioned in this video authentic and will it work..?

Tags: scripture, shiva, puranas, gods, planets

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DqgBLCibUqQ

please guide on this matter .. if not authentic can you please tell what mantra to chant to collectively please all planets and if know please recommend working upay/mantra for kaal sarp dosh